# In One Public Site on Sharepoint 2013 I don't see a lot of applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to add more applications? In another Public Site Collection I see about 32 applications, but here only a few.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most "applications" are added through activation of features in SharePoint. So go to Site Settings on the site collection that have all the 32 applications and look at **Site Collection Features** and **Manage Site Features**. You might find that those features are not active on your new site collection.

Comment: Specifically, look for one called "Team Collaboration Lists", which may be listed as "Listy pracy zespołowej".

Comment: Yes it worked Great. It was with different Icon